# pyodbc.Error: ('HYC00', '[HYC00] Unknown statement option (Set) (10) (SQLSetStmtAttr)')

Tags: python, database, postgresql, pyodbc

i tried to use a query with 2 parameters in pyodbc but i allways get the same error:
pyodbc.Error: ('HYC00', '[HYC00] Unknown statement option (Set) (10) (SQLSetStmtAttr)')
all attempts at fixing it resulted in the same error.
If i just use one parameter in the query it works without a problem

this is the code that results in the error:

```
name = "'Test'"
street = "'TestStreet'"
testQuery = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name = ? and street = ?"
testRes = dbCon.cursor()
params = (name, street)
testRes.execute(testQuery, params)
```

i also tried:

```
name = "Test"
street = "TestStreet"
```

```
testRes.execute(testQuery, (name, street))

testRes.execute(testQuery, ("'Test'", "'TestStreet'"))
```

Comment: the quesy string ends with a semicolon`;`....

Comment: when i try it with a semicolon i get a different error, the query works just fine if i only use one ? and variable

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes in your parameter values can be the cause of problem. Single quotes usually don't need to be used around placeholders when utilizing parameterized queries. The parameterization and quotation are handled  by Pyodbc.
Try this updated code:

```
name = "Test"
street = "TestStreet"
testQuery = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name = ? and street = ?"
testRes = dbCon.cursor()
params = (name, street)
testRes.execute(testQuery, params)
```

Replace your actual database connection object for dbCon.
Hope it's helpful :)